# Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 4.1.2 wifi disconnects when my screen goes off

Tags: connection-issues

Whenever i turn my screen off for an extended period of time, my tablet disconnects from wifi. I remember there being a setting on my old phone to do this, which i didn't use, with reason. However i can find no such setting for this on my tablet. Ive downloaded a few apps to help with this "screen off wifi off" or something like that, but the apps only seem to break the wifi in all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Wi-Fi sleep policy to "Never"

For Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) and later:

1) Navigate to Menu > Settings > WiFi and select the menu button again. 
2) Select Options, Advanced
3) Set “Keep WiFi on during sleep” to “Always”

Comment: I've had this problem for a looong time, I've no idea how the setting got set to "Never" but now its "always". Thank you.